# Under what conditions can I make a bounding argument when I have weak instruments?

Tags: econometrics, measurement-error, instrumental-variables, endogeneity, bounds

The model of interest is 
$$
y = \alpha + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \epsilon
$$
In the population, $E[\epsilon|x_1]\neq 0$ and $E[\epsilon|x_2]\neq 0$, so OLS estimates of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are biased.

Suppose that I know, from theory, that the bias will be downward for $\beta_1$ and upward for $\beta_2$.

I've got instruments $Z$ ($N\times k$ where $k\geq 2$) that satisfy the exclusion restriction (they are uncorrelated with $y$ except through their effect on $x_1$ and $x_2$) but that only weakly satisfy the inclusion restriction of being correlated with $x_1$ and $x_2$.  This is a weak instrument problem.  Following [Stock and Yogo](http://scholar.harvard.edu/stock/publications/testing-weak-instruments-linear-iv-regression), I calculate the [Cragg-Donald](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/econometric-theory/article/div-classtitletesting-identifiability-and-specification-in-instrumental-variable-modelsdiv/2905FDCF6AB4136C4C0F18C87CBE7CE5) statistic. The matrix isn't singular, so I'm not under-identified.  But the minimum eigenvalue is well below the Stock/Yogo critical values.  In short, my instruments are fairly bad.

Now, say that $\hat\beta_{OLS} = [0,0]$, and $\hat\beta_{2SLS} = [2, -2]$.  I can easily defend an assumption that $\hat\beta_{OLS} - \beta = [-, +]$.  I have read that weak instruments bias 2SLS estimates toward the OLS estimate.

**So can I therefore claim that $\hat\beta_{2SLS} = [2, -2]$ is a lower bound to $\beta$?  Seems too easy.**

Let's recast 2SLS as linear control functions:
$$
x_1 = Z\gamma_1 + \eta_1
$$

$$
x_2 = Z\gamma_2 + \eta_2
$$
The control functions estimator is 
$$
y = \alpha + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \delta_1\hat\eta_1 + \delta_2\hat\eta_2+ \epsilon
$$

and we know that $\hat\beta_{2sls} = \hat\beta_{CF}$.  Say that $Z$ is a weak set of instruments because it is mis-measured.  That would mean that $\gamma$ is too small (attenuation), and thus the variance of $\hat\eta$ will be too big.

Could I say that $\hat\eta = \eta + \mathcal{N}(0,var)$?  If so, then my control functions estimator has mismeasured regressors.  Given that these mismeasured regressors are correlated (by assumption) with the endogenous variables $x$, estimates of $\beta$ will be biased because of attenuation in $\hat\eta$.  If I'm willing to assume that $cov(\eta_1, x_1)<0$ and $cov(\eta_2, x_2)>0$, then it follows that $\beta_{CF}$ will be biased upwards and downwards, respectively.

(I think that all of the above require (or at least are simplified by) an assumption that $x_1\perp x_2$)

Am I missing something?  Are there additional assumptions that I need to make the above hold?  Under what conditions could it go wrong?

Also, assume that $\beta_{CF}$ is statistically significant (i.e. different from zero) after accounting for uncertainty in the first stage.  Assuming that $\beta_{CF}$ is bounded as above, could anything make my interval estimates *increase* rather than decrease?

Comment: If you have weak instrument, your true 'standard error' around your estimate is usually very large. So I guess you can't give convincing argument about the bounds with that point estimates. Later question depends on what kind of asymptotics you believe in. There is certainly an asymptotics that tells you eta hat converges to normal, but I wouldn't buy that given the weak instrument situation. I would consider using asymptotically pivotal statistics that doesn't depend on the 'strength' of the instrument. (e.g. Anderson-Rubin stat, see a series of Kleibergen's work for example.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the AR test.  It's fairly simple and might solve my problem.